# How to translate "Je fais marcher le carburateur"?

Tags: expressions, translation, french

What would be a good translation of "*je fais marcher le carburateur*" in English.

It is an expression to say that you are thinking intensively, using your brain a lot.

Comment: *You can see the gears turning*? (I don’t speak French, but the carburettor thing seemed relevant. :) )

Comment: I speak some French and it's "I run the carburetor".

Comment: @Lordology Not exactly.  More”I’m getting the carburettor running”.

Comment: "I'm getting my brain into gear" seems the closest parallel, given @Tuffy's inchoative restriction.

Comment: *Je fai**s** marcher le carburateur* is not common in French. Google only find one occurence outside this question. I would expect something like *je fais chauffer les neurones* to express what you wrote.

Comment: You might say "I really had to use my noggin."

Comment: Please provide a sample context, in English, where the English equivalent should appear. Make sure it's clear from the context what the expression is supposed to emphasize. Also, how informal is it?